# Why @autoreleasepool is 6 times faster than NSAutoreleasePool?

Tags: objective-c

Please help me out why @autoreleasepool is  6 times faster than NSAutoreleasePool.

Please open-->
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Then go to Common Issues While Converting a Project -- 
go to 3rd bullet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, it's all going to boil down to a call to objc_autoreleasePoolPush and objc_autoreleasePoolPop. The question then is: how much overhead does [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; and [pool drain]; add on top of those calls, since it has to have them internally.

The answer is apparently, "relatively quite a bit". A naive implementation of it would have to allocate an entire object and free it, but we can safely assume Apple has optimized NSAutoreleasePool more than that (say, by caching pool instances). Nonetheless, there's going to be some overhead in getting the objects involved relative to just a function call.

Comment: `NSAutoreleasePool` allocates an `NSAutoreleasePool` object (or fetches an existing one from a cache); `@autoreleasepool` does not. `NSAutoreleasePool` sends several Objective-C messages; `@autoreleasepool` does not.